# Implementation of RBAC with Postgres + Firestore

Tags: postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, rbac

I'm in the process of implementing an authentication + authorization system for my web application, and I'm struggling to decide how to implement the authorization part. This is what I've decided on, so far:

- **For the authentication process** I'll be using Firebase. After some research it stood between Firebase and AWS Cognito, and Firebase seemed to be more mature. The solution is secure, saves me a lot of hassle, and there's no point reinventing the wheel.
- **For storing additional user data** I'll use Firestore. It seems like this will make my life easier for performing user tasks, like updating personal information, and saving/retrieving user state in the onboarding process etc.
- **For the server side** I'm using Kotlin + Postgres, mainly because I want to know these technologies better.
- **For the permission model** I'll be using RBAC. This is mainly because it's flexible, and I've gotten some experience with it using AWS.

Now, for the RBAC implementation my idea is to keep the roles, policies and user groups in the Postgres database, while keeping my users in the Firebase (+ Firestore).

I'm really just looking for input on best practices, and if anyone has done something like this before.
There seems to be a lot of articles covering the authentication process, but not so many covering good authorization system implementations.

Any tips will be very much appreciated.